# Should I add node.js to my maven build process?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, maven, build

I'm working on a mature Java web app being built with Maven.

The application evolves and now an important part of the development is being made with Javascript in the frontend.

Now I would like to get advantage of the rich ecosystem of Javascript based tools (Less/Sass, Typescript, ES6, React...) to improve my client-side code.

I'm trying to use specific maven plugins for each case but I'm finding that the existent tools are poorly mantained or simply nonexistent. Looks like node.js is the way to go here.

On the other side I'm reluctant to add a node.js "bridge" like `frontend-maven-plugin`. Looks like a great plugin and a good solution to my problem, but I don't like the idea of adding a completely separated build toolchain to my project. Some of my coworkers would be confused, too.

Another important aspect to take into account: I would like to preserve as much as possible the fast edit-save-test workflow of html/js that we have now with the jetty plugin.

The options I see are:

- Add frontend-maven-plugin, get used to it, and move on.
- Use a specific Maven plugin for each case
- Use a specific frontend library/framework like Wro4j
- Other options...

Option 1 has the problem of the "radically different toolchain". Options 2 and 3 are Ok but I can´t find support for React JSX transformation, for example.

I have the feeling that something more mature or robust should exist in the open source ecosystem but I just can´t find it.

What can I do?

Comment: Having tried this, I had better luck keeping the JS build and Java build separate. `gulp && mvn` is nice and easy, especially if you end up with folks working only on the JS side of things.

Comment: @ssube: It's an option, too. But I'm afraid it would be a problem for other aspects of the project, like the Eclipse integration or the Jenkins automated jobs...

Comment: Eclipse isn't going to help much for building JavaScript apps anyways, and it should make no difference to Jenkins. Just have two repos, one for Java and one for JavaScript. It will save you a ton of time and effort.

Comment: Jenkins and most other CI tools have few problems running two tools from the path. At my job, depending on how closely the UI and server are tied (we do a lot of service-oriented stuff), we typically have a single build task with a step for gulp and a step for maven.